# Black & white sixties episode where a spacecraft is unable to depart the planet

Tags: story-identification, tv, space, planets

I believe it's a sixties T.V. item, possibly from *The Twilight Zone* or *The Outer Limits*. It is not "Death Ship."

This crew land and can not secure takeoff again no matter what they try. The plot has similarities to "Death Ship" in as much as their ship (craft) appears to be replicated nearby. The episode follows all the methods they attempt to secure liftoff, unsuccessfully.

Comment: Was their ship replicated prior their landing? Or it was just the same ship from another time or dimension ?

Comment: You may want to have a look at the advice here for making your question easier to answer:  https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question  One question I have in particular is what kind of spaceship was it?  Was it a rocket, or a saucer (the saucer prop from "Death Ship" was the one from *The Forbidden Planet*), or some other shape?

Comment: It sure sounds like "Death Ship" to me. In that story, the crew does make several attempts to lift off, always unsuccessful, and the nearby ship is not only a replica of their own ship but contains replicas of the crew.

Comment: If you think it's not Death Ship, is it because you remember some specific details that weren't in Death Ship, or is it just that you watched Death Ship and it seemed unfamiliar in a non-specific way?

Comment: Thankyou everyone! The craft is a replica (of itself), it is saucer like. In "Death ship", there is a sequence where they take off again and land. BTW I'm "happy to be wrong" etc. The telltale sequence for me is one where they open the "windows" of their craft one by one, to reveal no other replica craft, until the very last window, where their hopes are dashed. Thankyou all for your replies! Kind regards, m

Comment: Why can they not take off? Is it because the ship is being constantly sabotaged and/or mysteriously breaking?

Comment: Maury, it appears that an "unknown force" renders all real world technology null & void. I.E. everything works however actual lift off is prevented perhaps because it would cause an imbalance that triggers the phenomenon in the first instance?